# Creating URI with a list query param for JAX-RS

Tags: java, javascript, html, jax-rs

So JAX-RS can accept a query param as a list.  It does this by flattening fields so that

`users/query?from=100&to=200&orderBy=age&orderBy=name`

becomes

```
from: 100
to: 200
orderBy: ["age", "name"]
```

I'm using AngularJS to make my client side application,  How do would I construct this URI string without manually building it?

Comment: It depends what client-side technology you are using. You've only mentioned Javascript so far. Are you using plain Javascript, or something like AngularJS, JQuery, Knockout, ...?

Comment: I'm using Angular.  Will edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular, this is pretty simple. After defining your resource, let's call it `MyResource` you can have it injected in e.g. a controller the usual way. Then just do

```
MyResource.query({from: 100, to: 200, more: 'params as you like'}, ...);
```

With optional callbacks for successful or error response. This obviously also works for other methods on the resource.

Although I didn't try it, I would say you could also use an array of values for a param, like this

```
MyResource.query({orderBy: ['age', 'name']);
```

Seems to be in Angular since [February 2013](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1921).

Comment: I see this working for normal primitive field types. But in my case where field names are repeated, the normal object model does not work.  For example, if I want to `GET /index?orderBy=age&orderBy=name`, I wouldn't be able to build the URI with the given method.

Comment: why would you send a field twice? Does your server read both of them? In that case, you're better off combining multiple values into the same field or introducing as many extra fields as needed.